# Print a report of adoquery results

Tags: c++builder, fastreport

I would like to ask how can I print or create a report of results of a query which are being displayed in a `TdbGrid`? I try to connect `datasource` of `dbgrid`,`frxDataset` and `frxReport` but I miss something in the proccess...I use embarcadero XE 3 if that matters. I paste th code below although I know it is not correct:

```
frxReport1->DataSet=frxDBDataset1;
frxReport1->Report->PrepareReport();
frxReport1->Report->ShowPreparedReport();
frxReport1->Export(PDFExport1);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Embarcadero product is called c++builder, not visual c++ (Microsoft product). Change the tags of your question otherwise you will not reach the right persons.

Comment: There are lot of official video tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/user/FastReportsInc/videos?view=1